# How do I create a hyperlinked list from a JSON array

Tags: javascript, html, json, knockout.js

I've got a list of universities that I have generated from a json file, and I want to add a hyperlink for each university in the list generated so that I can navigate to each of their respective university pages.

**HTML**

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: university">
   <li data-bind="text: university"></li>
</ul>
```

I have been using knockout.js to get the json data to appear in the html and I was wondering whether there was a way to do this without hardcoding each link into the html?

**JSON file**

```
{
"universities": [
    {
        "university": "Cambridge"
    },
    {
        "university": "Oxford"
    },
    {
        "university": "UEA"
    }
]
}
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Take a look at the [`attr` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html).

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16364460/knockout-html-href

Comment: Where do you want your anchor to point to? "~/Universities/Cambridge" ? Anchor href has to be generated based on some piece of data. data-bind="attr: {href:'link'}"

Comment: "services/profile.jsp?uni=Cambridge" would be where the link would go.

Would I add:

    "href: "services/profile.jsp?uni=Cambridge"

to the json file and then call it how you've mentioned in the html? @MyP3uK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your **HTML** should look like

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/H38xt/)

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: universities">
    <li> <a data-bind="text: university, attr: { href: 'services/profile.jsp?uni=' + university }"></a> </li>
</ul>
```